# Why does callvirt IL instruction cause recursive invocation in virtual methods?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

IL doesn't always use `callvirt` instruction for `virtual` methods in a case like this:

```
class MakeMeASandwich{
  public override string ToString(){
    return base.ToString();
  }
}
```

In this case, it is said that IL will produce `call` instead of `callvirt` where `callvirt` is produced to check whether `variable` is `null` or not and throws `NullReferenceException` otherwise.

1. Why does a recursive invocation happen till stack overflow if `callvirt` is used instead of `call`?
2. If `call` is used, then when does it check whether the instance variable it uses to call the methods is null or not?

Comment: @Lucero:Nope I am reading a book about it and it came to my mind when I couldn't find an answer in the book.

Comment: I have (I think) clarified what I believe to be your question `2`. If I'm wrong, just rollback my revision :)

Comment: @AakashM: Well actually it was what I was asking however, it seems `callvirt` doesn't check whether the variable is empty or not :)

Comment: @Braveyard `callvirt` performs a null check; `call` does not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does a recursive invocation happen till stack overflow if callvirt is used instead of call?

Because then your code is exactly the same as:

```
override string ToString()
{
    return this.ToString();
}
```

Which clearly is an infinite recursion, provided that the method given is the most-overriding version of ToString.

> If call is used, then how come it checks whether the instance variable it uses to call the methods is null or not?

The question is not answerable because the question assumes a falsehood. The call instruction does *not* check to see if the reference to the receiver is null or not, so asking *why the call instruction checks for null* doesn't make any sense.

Let me rephrase that for you into some better questions:

> Under what circumstances does the C# compiler generate a call vs a callvirt?

If the C# code is doing a *non virtual call* on a *virtual method* then the compiler *must* generate a call, not a callvirt. The only time this happens really is when using `base` to call a virtual method.

If the C# code is doing a *virtual call* then the compiler *must* generate a callvirt.

If the C# code is doing a *non virtual call* on a *non virtual method* then the compiler can choose to generate either call or callvirt. Either will work. The C# compiler typically chooses to generate a callvirt.

> The call instruction does not automatically do a null check, but callvirt does. If the C# compiler chooses to generate a call instead of a callvirt, is it also obligated to generate a null check?

No. The C# compiler can skip the null check if the receiver is already known to not be null. For example, if you said `(new C()).M()` for a non-virtual method M then it would be legal for the compiler to generate a `call` instruction without a null check. We know that (1) the method is not virtual, so it does not have to be a `callvirt`; we can choose whether to use `callvirt` or not.  And we know (2) that `new C()` is never null, so we do not have to generate a null check.

If the C# compiler does *not* know that the receiver is not null, then it will either generate a callvirt, or it will generate a null check followed by a call.

Comment: So you say "since `callvirt` is calling actual type which first implements the virtual method and at the point since `base` becomes `this`, it would itself recursively which causes `stackoverflow`"? Am I correct?

Comment: @Braveyard: Callvirt does two things. (1) it checks to see if the receiver is null. (2) if the receiver is not null then it looks up the method in the receiver's *virtual function table*, which tells the runtime *what is the version of this method that was on the most derived type* in the type hierarchy of the object. It then calls that method.

Comment: @Braveyard: I think that my series of articles explaining how virtual methods work might be of use to you. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/17/implementing-the-virtual-method-pattern-in-c-part-one.aspx

Comment: Thanks for all these responses. I started reading your  article already. Thanks.

Comment: Just one more question, `public override string ToString()` isn't considered a virtual method right? Only "public virtual string ToString()' considered `virtual` method?

Comment: @Braveyard: I would consider both to be virtual methods. Though really "virtual method" is not a very good name for the concept; I find it quite misleading and confusing. "Virtual" tells you nothing unless you already know what it means. It would have been better for all concerned if we had as an industry named them "overridable methods" -- describing what you can *do* with them -- or "indirect methods" -- describing how they work.

Comment: @EricLippert in Alexei Levenkov's comments to bmm6o's answer, and in hvd's answer, it is posited that a language other than C# could call an overriding method with `call`, and therefore `this` could be null.  Do you have any comments on that?

Comment: @phoog: Then odds are good that someone is eventually going to dereference null; this optimization might cause that dereference to happen later than it normally would. **If it hurts when you do that then don't do that.** Don't use languages that allow `this` to be null unless you enjoy random crashes.

Comment: @EricLippert: One thing I couldn't understand that even though I say `base.ToString()` instead of `this.ToString()` in the overriding method, why it still finds most-derived implementation of the `ToString()` when using `callvirt`? Lets say if I say `BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass(); baseClass.ToString()` would it check whether derived types are overriding it?

Comment: @Braveyard: If you use `base` then it is *never* a virtual call; it is a non-virtual call to the base class method. If you use `baseClass` then it is a virtual call and the method is looked up at runtime. That's the whole point of virtual calls.

Comment: @Braveyard if you say `BaseClass baseClass = new BaseClass();` then it's irrelevant whether derived types override the method, because *the receiver of the method call is not an instance of any derived type.*  More relevant would be the question "what if I have `BaseClass baseClass = this; baseClass.VirtualMethod();`?" In that case, the virtual call will go to the overriding method, if there is one, in the derived class.

Answer (score 3):

1. callvirt will call the MakeMeASandwich implementation, not the Object implementation.  This is how you get your stack overflow.
2. The initial call was with callvirt, which establishes that the reference is not null.  If control is inside this ToString implementation, you already know there is an object.

Comment: Could you please explain the item 1 little bit more? `callvirt` will call `MakeMeASandwich` one so it calls the `base`, why a stack overflow here?

Comment: 2 is probably not exactly correct - `this` could be null (since MakeMeASandwich.ToString could have been `call`'ed) and no additional checks will be made - should be reasonably easy to check by creating corresponding IL.

Comment: @Braveyard, just write IL and trace by hand - you'll see that if base.ToString is translated to `callvirt base.ToString` it is actually equal to `call MakeMeASandwich.ToString` since it uses the latest override for ToString.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Thanks for the recommendation, but I like to learn as much as I can before jumping into code side :-)

Comment: No coding needed: "write" as in take a pen and paper :). Draw how `callvirt` discovers what to call based on object pointer and its virtual method table... And that manually step through 4-5 IL statements written on paper.

Answer (score 3):

1. `call` is used because it is known right there which method to call, and it should not be looked up at runtime (`callvirt` would cause the code to call the method defined at the most specific class, which then causes your stack overflow).
2. `callvirt` implies a null check, whereas `call`does not.

Answer (score 2):

Callvirt calls the most derived method available. In this case this is MakeMeASandwich.ToString().

The purpose of callvirt is not only to check for null, but also to perform a virtual method call.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does a recursive invocation happen till stack overflow if callvirt is used instead of call?

As others have answered, `callvirt` calls the method virtually. It's as if you had written

```
public override string ToString() {
    return ToString();
}
```

> If call is used, then how come it checks whether the instance variable it uses to call the methods is null or not?

Others have mentioned that you already know that `this` is not null. That's incorrect. *If* `callvirt` is used to call `MakeMeASandwich.ToString`, then yes, `this` cannot be null. However, there is no requirement that `callvirt` is used to call your function. Other languages do allow you to write the call in such a way that `call` opcode is generated, and in that case, no null check is performed. I think C++/CLI allows it with `makeMeASandwich->MakeMeASandwich::ToString()`, but I'm not entirely sure. You can't know for sure that `this` isn't null unless you check.

Comment: Could you please explain "calling a method virtually? little bit more? I know that `virtual` means that you can override it in derived class.

Comment: @Braveyard: calling a method virtually means getting the address of the method from a table of virtual methods.  `System.Object`, for example, defines a slot in the virtual method table for (among others) a `ToString()` method.  The method that *goes into the slot* can be defined by overriding classes.  If an overriding class doesn't define a method for the slot, then the method defined by the most-derived class in the inheritance chain is used instead.

Comment: @Braveyard To use a concrete example, with `class A { public virtual void f(); }`, `class B : A { public override void f(); }`, `A a = new B();`, virtually calling (`callvirt`) `A::f()` actually ends up calling `B::f()`, while directly calling (`callvirt`) `A::f()` means you call the implementation as provided by `A`. It's pretty much the main question rephrased :)

Comment: @hvd: Thanks a lot, it was a clarifying answer.

Comment: @hvd don't you mean to say "...while directly calling (`call`) `A::f()` means you call the implementation as provided by `A`"?

Comment: @phoog Yes, I do, thanks. Unfortunately it's too late to edit.

Comment: hvd: I realize it's too late to edit; I just wanted to make sure that @Braveyard caught the mistake, so as not to be confused.